# Highlight string formatting expressions and method operators in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How to highlight Python's string interpolation operators in PyCharm?
I mean, those operators are used for 
formatting expressions:

```
' %(variable)s ' %dict
```

and formatting method:

```
'{variable}'.format(variable='foo')
```

[in sublime it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBsAy.png)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I want PyCharm to highlight %(variable)s and {variable} in string literals, so they have different color. How can I do it?

Comment: Basicaly I want PyCharm to highlight with different color anything I can specify with regular expression . Specifically I want it to highlight %(variable)s and {variable} .

Comment: In you example you want the text `variable` to be highlighted?  That sounds like a great idea, but I do not think it is currently supported.  Try a feature request here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: I want text %(variable)s or {variable}  or %s(d,f....) to be highlighted, just like in sublime. where variable can be anything(alphanumeric_)...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there seems no way to do this. However, if you're using Python new enough (3.6+), you can use ["f-strings"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

```
'{variable}'.format(variable=some_value)
```

becomes

```
f'{some_value}'
```

and PyCharm highlights that nicely. (Tested with PyCharm 2018.1.1)